# Re-using symbolic evaluation for numerical evaluation

Tags: evaluation

I am creating a matrix of symbolic expressions "ResultSymbolic" , from a function which takes two symbolic Parameters: a scalar A, and an BxB Matrix M of symbolic expressions.

I have a second BxB Matrix of numerical values "Nums", which I am trying to plug into ResultSymbolic to get ResultNumerical:

```
 ResultNumerical = ResultSymbolic /. M -> Nums
```

If I do this, however, ResultNumerical looks exactly the same as ResultSymbolic.

ResultSymbolic takes a loooong time to compute, which is why I would love to be able to re-use it for ResultNumerical.

An example for "M" and "Nums" would be:

```
 M = {{M1,M2},{M3,M4}}; 
 Nums = {{1,2},{3,4}};
```

I now want to replace every occurence of "Mi" in "ResultSymbolic" with the corresponding entry in "Nums", to get ResultNumeric.

Comment: It's not clear from your question how the values in `nums` relate to the symbols in `resultsymbolic`. Is each entry in `nums` a value for a variable? Can you give a minimal example (ie, `B == 2` or `3`)? Also, I think you mean [`/.`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html), and not `\.`.

Comment: I updated my post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the variables in `M` are the variables used in `ResultSymbolic`, this should work:

```
ResultNumerical = ResultSymbolic /. (Rule@@#&/@ Transpose[{Flatten[M],Flatten[Nums]}]);
```

Essentially, you just need to construct a list of rules where each symbol is substituted with the appropriate number. `Flatten` will preserve the order of each lists, assuming `M` and `Nums` will always have the same dimensions, and transposing brings each variable next to its numerical value. Then each pair has its head replaced with `Rule` to make it a list of rules.

Answer (score 2):

This is really more of an addendum to @eyorble's perfectly good answer. I wanted to add a bit of an example to illustrate what's going on.

Suppose you have a matrix of variables and a corresponding matrix of values that they take:

```
vars = Partition[ToExpression[CharacterRange["α", "ι"]], 3]
nums = Partition[Range[9], 3]

(* {{α, β, γ}, 
    {δ, ε, ζ}, 
    {η, θ, ι}} 

   {{1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}} *)
```

(OP called my `vars` matrix `M` in the question, but I've changed it to `vars` because single capital letters should be avoided in *Mathematica*, and it's nice to have meaningful variable names.)

Now suppose that your `resultsymbolic` is a matrix of some horrific functions of these variables:

```
resultssymbolic = Partition[f @@@ Table[RandomSample[Flatten[vars], 4], {4}], 2]

(* {{f[ι, ζ, ε, θ], f[ζ, γ, θ, α]}, 
    {f[δ, θ, ζ, α], f[β, δ, η, α]}} *)
```

Then the numerical values can be substituted in with

```
resultssymbolic /. Flatten@MapThread[Rule, {vars, nums}, 2]

(* {{f[9, 6, 5, 8], f[6, 3, 8, 1]}, 
    {f[4, 8, 6, 1], f[2, 4, 7, 1]}} *)
```

The key to making the substitution work is the list of replacement rules, which I constructed by [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html)ing the [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) function over `vars` and `nums` (at level 2):

```
Flatten@MapThread[Rule, {vars, nums}, 2]

(* {α -> 1, β -> 2, γ -> 3, δ -> 4, ε -> 5, ζ -> 6, η -> 7, θ -> 8, ι -> 9} *)
```

Notice that without the `Flatten` we'd end up with a list of replacement lists:

```
(* {{α -> 1, β -> 2, γ -> 3}, 
    {δ -> 4, ε -> 5, ζ -> 6}, 
    {η -> 7, θ -> 8, ι -> 9}} *)
```

Trying to use this to replace the values will fail because `ReplaceAll` will interpret it as three separate replacement rules, and return three distinct matrices:

```
resultssymbolic /. MapThread[Rule, {vars, nums}, 2]

(* {{{f[ι, ζ, ε, θ], f[ζ, 3, θ, 1]}, 
    {f[δ, θ, ζ, 1], f[2, δ, η, 1]}}, 

   {{f[ι, 6, 5, θ], f[6, γ, θ, α]}, 
    {f[4, θ, 6, α], f[β, 4, η, α]}}, 

   {{f[9, ζ, ε, 8], f[ζ, γ, 8, α]}, 
    {f[δ, 8, ζ, α], f[β, δ, 7, α]}}
  } *)
```

which is clearly not what we're after.